# Spring SimpleJdbcCall and Oracle Synonyms

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, spring-jdbc, synonym

After upgrading the Spring framework from <4.2.2.RELEASE> to <5.0.2.RELEASE> I can't call a stored procedure in my Oracle database using synonyms (SimpleJdbcCall). I noticed that as my code started to throw

Unable to determine the correct call signature - no procedure/function/signature for "name of my stored procedure"

exceptions. Then I debugged and found out that the stored procedure can't be found if it's behind a synonym. With the old Spring version that was not a problem. So what did they change and what can I do now? I read about retrieving the original Oracle connection from the Datasource and activating the synonym flag there: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html#setIncludeSynonyms_boolean_

But that does not seem to me to be a "beautiful" solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I did not find any other solution, I switched from SimpleJdbcCall to the usual Spring JdbcTemplate and called my stored procedure with

```
private jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(myDataSource);
try{
  CallableStatement callableStatement = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().prepareCall("{call PACKAGE_NAME.STORED_PROCEDURE_NAME}");
  callableStatement.executeUpdate();
} catch(SQLException e)
{
...
}
```

That worked fine then.

**Update**: The problem was fixed in Spring 5.0.4.RELEASE, consider https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16478